# Proximity Alerts Work, but ID selection isn't

Tags: android, textbox, alert, proximity

So, you may have seen my previous posts on problems adding proximity alerts in a scavenger hunt app and getting them to fire off.  The alerts are firing off, and seems to be just fine.  HOWEVER...I'm using an int ID variable to help determine what text gets displayed when a particular proximity alert is fired.  This works to an extent, but for whatever reason, the app defaults to the last ID that was entered in the addProximityAlert method, and only populates the text for that last ID, no matter what proximity alert fires off.

Here's the full code:

```
public class FCRun extends Activity implements LocationListener  {

private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCECHANGE_FOR_UPDATE = 1;                // in meters
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATE = 5000;                   // in Milliseconds
private static final long PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION = -1;                           // -1 is never expires
public static final String PROX_ALERT_INTENT = "com.kinghendo.android.frankcem.ProximityAlert";
//public static final int KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED = 0;
private LocationManager lm;
double latitude, longitude;
public String[] Screen;
private ProximityIntentReceiver proximityReceiver;
//private String[] locationList;

// setting default screen text
public TextView txtName;
public TextView txtInfo;
public TextView txtClue;



 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fcrun);

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Resources res = getResources();

        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.first);
        txtName.setText(Screen[0]);
        Log.i("txtName", "populated "+PROX_ALERT_INTENT);

        txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.first);
        txtInfo.setText(Screen[1]);
        Log.i("txtInfo", "populated "+PROX_ALERT_INTENT);

        txtClue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtClue);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.first);
        txtClue.setText(Screen[2]);
        Log.i("txtClue", "populated "+PROX_ALERT_INTENT);


     // Get the location Manager  (code from http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/location/android-location-based-services-example/)
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATE,
                MINIMUM_DISTANCECHANGE_FOR_UPDATE,
                this
        );

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
        proximityReceiver = new ProximityIntentReceiver(this);                      // registers ProximityIntentReceiver
        registerReceiver(proximityReceiver, filter);

        addProximityAlerts();

 }

 private void addProximityAlerts(){
     Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
     if (loc == null)
         Toast.makeText(this, "No location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     else
         addProximityAlert(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1, 0);

     addProximityAlert (38.042015, -84.492637, 10, 27);                 // test Awesome
     addProximityAlert (38.085705, -84.561101, 10, 26);                 // Test Home Location
     addProximityAlert (38.152649, -84.895205, 10, 25);                 // Test Office Location
     addProximityAlert (38.197871, -84.866924, 3, 1);                   // Information Center
     addProximityAlert (38.196001, -84.867435, 6, 2);                   // Goebel
     addProximityAlert (38.203191, -84.867674, 7, 3);                   // Chapel
     addProximityAlert (38.192173, -84.870451, 6, 4);                   // Confederate Cemetery
     addProximityAlert (38.193455, -84.868534, 2, 5);                   // O'Bannon
     addProximityAlert (38.193815, -84.864904, 2, 6);                   // Henry Clay Jr
     addProximityAlert (38.087388, -84.547503, 2, 7);                   // O'Hara
     addProximityAlert (38.191642, -84.870967, 5, 8);                   // Daniel Boone
 }


private void addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude, int radius, int ID) {
    Log.i("TEST", "addProximityAlert "+latitude+", "+longitude+", "+radius+", " +ID+", " + PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION);
    Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
    intent.putExtra("ID", ID);
    PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //lm.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, radius, ID, proximityIntent);
    lm.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, radius, PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, proximityIntent);

}

public void onProximityAlert(int ID, boolean entering) {
    Log.i("TEST", "LOC " +latitude+", "+longitude);
    Log.i("TEST", "onProximityAlert ID="+ID+" entering: "+entering);


     switch (ID){
     case 1:
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.start);
        txtName.setText(Screen[0]);
        Log.i("txtName", "populated"+ID);

        txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.start);
        txtInfo.setText(Screen[1]);
        Log.i("txtInfo", "populated "+ID);

        txtClue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtClue);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.start);
        txtClue.setText(Screen[2]);
        Log.i("txtClue", "populated "+ID);
         break;
     case 2:
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.goebel);
        txtName.setText(Screen[0]);
        Log.i("txtName", "populated "+ID);

        txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.goebel);
        txtInfo.setText(Screen[1]);
        Log.i("txtInfo", "populated "+ID);

        txtClue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtClue);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.goebel);
        txtClue.setText(Screen[2]);
        Log.i("txtClue", "populated "+ID);
         break;
     case 3:
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.church);
        txtName.setText(Screen[0]);
        Log.i("txtName", "populated "+ID);

        txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.church);
        txtInfo.setText(Screen[1]);
        Log.i("txtInfo", "populated "+ID);

        txtClue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtClue);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.church);
        txtClue.setText(Screen[2]);
        Log.i("txtClue", "populated "+ID);
         break;
     case 4:
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.confederate);
        txtName.setText(Screen[0]);
        Log.i("txtName", "populated "+ID);

        txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.confederate);
        txtInfo.setText(Screen[1]);
        Log.i("txtInfo", "populated "+ID);

        txtClue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtClue);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.confederate);
        txtClue.setText(Screen[2]);
        Log.i("txtClue", "populated "+ID);
         break;
     case 5:
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.obannon);
        txtName.setText(Screen[0]);
        Log.i("txtName", "populated "+ID);

        txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.obannon);
        txtInfo.setText(Screen[1]);
        Log.i("txtInfo", "populated "+ID);

        txtClue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtClue);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.obannon);
        txtClue.setText(Screen[2]);
        Log.i("txtClue", "populated "+ID);
         break;
     case 6:
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hcj);
        txtName.setText(Screen[0]);
        Log.i("txtName", "populated "+ID);

        txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hcj);
        txtInfo.setText(Screen[1]);
        Log.i("txtInfo", "populated "+ID);

        txtClue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtClue);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hcj);
        txtClue.setText(Screen[2]);
        Log.i("txtClue", "populated "+ID);
         break;
     case 7:
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ohara);
        txtName.setText(Screen[0]);
        Log.i("txtName", "populated "+ID);

        txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ohara);
        txtInfo.setText(Screen[1]);
        Log.i("txtInfo", "populated "+ID);

        txtClue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtClue);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ohara);
        txtClue.setText(Screen[2]);
        Log.i("txtClue", "populated "+ID);
         break;
     case 8:
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.danielboone);
        txtName.setText(Screen[0]);
        Log.i("txtName", "populated "+ID);

        txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.danielboone);
        txtInfo.setText(Screen[1]);
        Log.i("txtInfo", "populated "+ID);

        txtClue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtClue);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.danielboone);
        txtClue.setText(Screen[2]);
        Log.i("txtClue", "populated "+ID);
         break;
     case 25:
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.toffice);
        txtName.setText(Screen[0]);
        Log.i("txtName", "populated "+ID);

        txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.toffice);
        txtInfo.setText(Screen[1]);
        Log.i("txtInfo", "populated "+ID);

        txtClue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtClue);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.toffice);
        txtClue.setText(Screen[2]);
        Log.i("txtClue", "populated "+ID);
         break;
     case 26:
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.thome);
        txtName.setText(Screen[0]);
        Log.i("txtName", "populated "+ID);

        txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.thome);
        txtInfo.setText(Screen[1]);
        Log.i("txtInfo", "populated "+ID);

        txtClue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtClue);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.thome);
        txtClue.setText(Screen[2]);
        Log.i("txtClue", "populated "+ID);
         break;
     case 27:
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tawesome);
        txtName.setText(Screen[0]);
        Log.i("txtName", "populated "+ID);

        txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tawesome);
        txtInfo.setText(Screen[1]);
        Log.i("txtInfo", "populated "+ID);

        txtClue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtClue);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tawesome);
        txtClue.setText(Screen[2]);
        Log.i("txtClue", "populated "+ID);
         break;
     default:
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.first);
        txtName.setText(Screen[0]);
        Log.i("txtName", "populated "+ID);

        txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.first);
        txtInfo.setText(Screen[1]);
        Log.i("txtInfo", "populated "+ID);

        txtClue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtClue);
        Screen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.first);
        txtClue.setText(Screen[2]);
        Log.i("txtClue", "populated "+ID);
        break;
     }
}

 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     //String provider = location.getProvider();
     latitude = location.getLatitude();
     longitude = location.getLongitude();

     Log.i("TEST", "lat: "+latitude+" lng: "+longitude+" "+PROX_ALERT_INTENT);

}

 @Override
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

 }
 @Override
 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

 }
 @Override
 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
 }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("TEST", "Close Out");
    lm.removeUpdates(this);
    unregisterReceiver(proximityReceiver);

}
```

}

Here's the Receiver Code...

```
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;
private WeakReference<FCRun> mActivity;
long lat, lon;

public ProximityIntentReceiver(FCRun activity) {
    mActivity = new WeakReference<FCRun>(activity);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
    Bundle results = getResultExtras(true);
    Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

    lat = intent.getLongExtra("location-lat ", lat);
    lon = intent.getLongExtra("location-lon ", lon);
    int ID = intent.getIntExtra("ID", 0);

    Log.i("ProximityIntentReceiver", "coordinate-lat " + lat );
    Log.i("ProximityIntentReceiver", "coordinate-lon " + lon );
    Log.i("ProximityIntentReceiver", String.format("ID: %d entering: %s", ID, entering?"true":"false"));
    FCRun a = mActivity.get();
    if (a != null)
        a.onProximityAlert(ID, entering);

 // Vibrate for 2 seconds
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(2000);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(FCRun.PROX_ALERT_INTENT), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);        

    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle("Location Alert ")
    .setContentText("Entering Point of Interest")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .build(); // available from API level 11 and onwards

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);
 }
```

}

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Hendo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to have multiple `PendingIntent` instances in `addProximityAlert` and your `PendingIntent`s are considered equal because they only differ in the content of the extras.  The [documentation for `PendingIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) explains this:

> A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This means that, even if its owning application's process is killed, the PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have been given it. If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid, and can thus call cancel() to remove it.
>
> Because of this behavior, it is important to know when two Intents are considered to be the same for purposes of retrieving a PendingIntent. A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents, expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does not happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the same ones defined by Intent.filterEquals. If you use two Intent objects that are equivalent as per Intent.filterEquals, then you will get the same PendingIntent for both of them.

It also gives guidance on how to fix it:

> There are two typical ways to deal with this.
>
> If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at
>   the same time (such as to use as two notifications that are both shown
>   at the same time), then you will need to ensure there is something
>   that is different about them to associate them with different
>   PendingIntents. This may be any of the Intent attributes considered by
>   Intent.filterEquals, or different request code integers supplied to
>   getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getActivities(Context, int,
>   Intent[], int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), or
>   getService(Context, int, Intent, int).

So probably the easiest way to fix it is to use the `ID` as the request code (assuming it's unique). E.g.:

Change

```
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

to

```
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: That worked Hex...well...mostly. 4 of the GPS points fired off their proximityalerts, and displayed the proper text.  The other 6 either gave me  an alert notification and didn't display text, or didn't give me a notification at all.  I'm going to revisit my GPS points and radius', and see if that helps.  Not sure what else to do if that doesn't help it.  Thanks Hex, for your insight and gracious assistance.

Comment: Great, glad it helped. Please upvote and/or accept the answer if you found it useful. I see the radius for some of your proximity alerts is quite small, so that may be why some of them don't fire as the accuracy of the GPS may not be good enough if it doesn't have a lock on enough satellites to be within the radius of your points.